# Trying to get the average monthly revenue for each month per industry. Need HELP in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been banging my head on the wall trying to figure out why the AVG function does not work in BigQuery:

```
WITH MonthlyRevenue AS (
  SELECT u.Industry,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM o.Purchase_Date) AS Month,
  SUM(CAST(o._Invoice_ AS FLOAT64)) AS MonthlyRevenue
  FROM `shipbob-402223.OrderData.Order_Data` AS o
  INNER JOIN `shipbob-402223.OrderData.User_Level_Data` AS u
  ON o.Userid = u.Userid
  GROUP BY u.Industry, Month
)
SELECT
  Industry,
  Month,
  AVG(MonthlyRevenue) AS AverageMonthlyRevenue
FROM MonthlyRevenue
GROUP BY Industry, Month
ORDER BY Industry, Month;
```

Without the Average revenue line my output looks like the screenshot.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKir0.png)

With the AVG line included I receive this error: "No matching signature for aggregate function AVG for argument types:

```
STRUCT\<Industry STRING, Month INT64, MonthlyRevenue FLOAT64\>. Supported signatures: AVG(INT64); AVG(FLOAT64); AVG(NUMERIC); AVG(BIGNUMERIC); AVG(INTERVAL) at \[13:3\]
```

I was trying to get the Average Monthly Revenue by Industry per month.

Comment: The issue you're encountering is because of the name conflict, you can try a different name for MonthlyRevenue column